# Android :Export Android Project as jar

Tags: java, android, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i have developed one android project,(it has some resource files,and jni part ,and also containing some external .so file) which i want to use in another android applications,

if i make a project as a library project i cant use the resource files in another project,so that i export my project as jar,in that jar containing all following folders

```
assets
bin
com/package containing all classes
libs/ all .so files
res
obj
META-INF
```

in my another application i put my jar file in lib folder and add to the project path

the problem is ,i cant access the class and .so files  and  resource from the jar.
and also i tried to put all so file in new project libs folder also.

i got unsatisfied link error,is't possible to do this.or else do you have any idea?

```
NOTE: i don't want to add the project as Reference Project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All Android project doesn't works as a Simple `.jar` file As you want to use resources from it.

Only Way You have to make Android Project as an `Android Library Project` to use resources and `.so` files from it..

**Update:**

Look at http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: if you make project as Android Library project means u can only access the class files but u cant access resource files

Comment: I have included poi.jar file to read data from xml file and it is working fine.....so how can you say we can't work with external jar files. @Mr.Cool how can you use the resources from jar file...I think it is not possible. you can use only class files in jar but not the other resources...you are wrong.

Comment: If you have to use drawables and other resources then Android Project as a Library is works for you. Because you can access Resource from that project. Haven't you used `Android Sherlock Libraries` and `V4 support Libraries` in your Project??

Comment: @Pragnani - Are you sure you can access drawables from your Android project .jar files??? If yes then I like to know the way..

Comment: @user370305 I haven't said that....it is not possible to access drawables from jar files

Comment: @ user370305 if i make a project as library project i only get the class files inside that then how to use resource in another project

Comment: Then you have to just `import .R` file of that Android Library Project in your application, Now you can access any resources from that Library..

Answer (score 0):

android application run with .apk file not .jar file

Comment: @Ayaz Ali Khatri you wrongly understood my question read it again

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when using gradle to build your project

1. Generate [android aar file](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)

   - export your library project from eclipse to android studio, you may wanna see [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)
   - use gradle to build your Android Library, and find library aar file in PROJECT_ROOT/build/libs/ folder
2. Reference your android project to this aar library

   - drag the aar file to your project, let's say in PROJECT_ROOT/aars/ folder
   - set this aar file as a maven repo,
     add these codes in your project gradle build file (PROJECT_ROOT/build.gradle)

     ```
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
         flatDir {
             dirs 'aars'
         }
     }
     ```
   - Reference the aar library, lets say your library source package is com.example.library, version is 1.0(you may find it inside your library project AndroidManifest file) and android aar file name is mylib.aar, then add these codes inside the dependencies block

     ```
     compile 'com.example.library:mylib:1.0@aar'
     ```
3. gradle sync your android project and have fun.